# C# Visual Studio 2010 embed exe icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have made an anplication with Visual Studio C# 2010 Express, and I have set my icon in the project properties -> application -> ressources ...

like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/339stzf7.aspx)

but when I try to launch my app, I need to copy my icon in the same folder of the application

How can I embed it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've done is to add a pointer to a file on disk; instead, it's probably simpler to link the icon directly into your executable as a resource.

This page shows how to add an Icon resource to your .NET application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx

Once you've done this, you can point to the application icon that is compiled into your program, and it won't have to live on disk in a separate file.

Comment: I was my fault I have set the form Icon with Expression blend, not the app Icon, and i have set the icon app with VS, problem solved